# filling seeds in latin hypercube - lhs for r

Tags: r, parameters, hypercube

having an simple latin hypercube

```
mylhs<-randomLHS(3, k=2)
plot(mylhs,ylim=c(0:1),xlim=c(0:1),pch="+")
abline(v=1/3)
abline(v=2/3)
abline(h=1/3)
abline(h=2/3)
```

I want to augment it by 6 more seeds so that in every cell is at least one.
The next step would be to add 9 seeds more, so that in every cell are exactly 2. For knowing what I mean by cell, it might help to draw the plot and lines

that's probably not the original idea of lhs, but is it possible?

the `augmentLHS` doesn't full fill the task (only by accident)

```
mylhs2<-optAugmentLHS(mylhs, m=6)
points(mylhs2,col="red")
abline(v=1/3)
abline(v=2/3)
abline(h=1/3)
abline(h=2/3)
```

Comment: what package is `randomLHS` from? doesnt appear to be from base R

Comment: It lhs package. But doing it with other packages ... or functions would be fine too.